# Work around typedef u8 to use C++11 u8 string literal

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef, string-literals

I'd like to use the new C++ u8 string literal prefix ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)).

However the code base I'm using already typedefs *u8* to be *unsigned char*.
I can't practically move headers around or #undef around them.

How may I work around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does not matter that `u8` has been defined as a macro. A string literal, whether or not it has an encoding prefix, is a single preprocessor token. The `u8` prefix will not undergo macro replacement. There is actually an example in Appendix C that demonstrates this:

```
#define u8 "abc"
const char *s = u8"def";  // Previously "abcdef", now "def"
```

Comment: Was about to post sample code. I can verify VS 2017 currently compiles this just fine. I last tested with either VS 2013 or earlier VS 2017.  I won't delete the question because you deserve points for assisting so quickly :)

Comment: This works because the standard says that when string concatenating there should be a space between the strings: u8"def" should have been generating a warning or error previously, and you have had ***years*** to change it to u8 "def"

Comment: @GemTaylor Where does it say that?

Comment: Well clang does :-): error: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wreserved-user-defined-literal]

Comment: @GemTaylor I don't think that diagnostic means what you think it means